# No states shown for selecting countries except United states in udropship vendor setting

Tags: magento, billing

I have a problem regarding the state selection in udorpship.

Let me elaborate my problem.When I login as a vendor and on "Setting->Billing Information", when I select the country except United States the dropdown select to choose "States" doesnot get clicked.

Is this the problem regarding the extension or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a bug. in your system you have states setup only for US.
if you need other states you need upload them directly in db.
this might be a good example for that
http://www.sycha.com/magento-add-custom-state-province-region-country